# react-native re-run function on navigating back

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm using react-navigation to navigate between screens, now in my "cases.js" I have a fetch method that gets the cases from the API when the user click on one it loads another page with the clicked case to either accept or deny the case itself.

Either way the user will be redirected to the "cases.js" page if the user accepts the case I no longer need the case to be available on the "cases.js" page list.

Here is my cases.js file

```
export default class PendingCases extends Component {

  constructor(props) {

    super(props);

    this.state = { cases : [], user : '', refreshing : false }

  }

  componentDidMount = async () => {

    await this._getUser();

    await this._getCases();

  }

  _getUser = async () => {

    let user = await AsyncStorage.getItem('user');

    await this.setState({ user : JSON.parse(user) })

  }

  _getCases = async () => {

    try {

      await this.setState({ refreshing : true })

      let pendingCases = await fetch('http://192.168.1.101:1337/user/cases?status=pending&userType=patient&id=' + this.state.user.id);

      let response = await pendingCases.json();

      await this.setState({ cases : response.cases });

      await this.setState({ refreshing : false })

    } catch (err) {

      console.log(err);

    }

  }

  render() {

    let casesArray = this.state.cases.map((singleCase, index) => {
      return (
        <View key={ index }>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={ () => this.props.navigation.navigate('SelectedCaseDetails') } style={ styles.caseButton }>
            <View>
              <View style={{ marginBottom: 10, marginTop: 5 }}>
                <LinearTextGradient locations={[0, 1]} start={{x: 0, y: 0}} end={{x: 1, y: 0}} colors={['#a4d294', '#3ac6f3']} style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>
                  {singleCase.doctor.name}
                </LinearTextGradient>
                <Text style={{ position: 'absolute', right: 0, fontWeight: '600', color: 'black'}}> 00231 </Text>
              </View>
              <View style={{ marginBottom: 10 }}>
                <Text> {singleCase.additionalInformation} </Text>
              </View>
              <View style={{ marginBottom: 10, flex : 1, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
              <Image style={ styles.statusImage } source={require('../images/status.png')} />
                <Text style={{ marginRight : 30, color : 'rgba(0, 0, 0, .8)', flex : 8}}>
                 Status <Text style={{ color : 'rgb(240, 151, 166)', marginLeft : 60 }}> {singleCase.status} </Text> </Text>
                <Text style={{ position: 'absolute', right: 0, fontWeight: '300', color: 'grey'}}> { parsedDate } </Text>
              </View>
            </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>

        </View>
      )
    });

    return (
      <View>
        { casesArray }
      </View>
    )

  }

}
```

How can I re-run the `this._getCases()` function when I redirect the user from the one-level deep page ?

I'm redirecting the user the same way as navigating to any other screen
`this.props.navigation.navigate('CasesScreen')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your component is already mounted, you can use `react-navigation's` [listeners](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html#addlistener-subscribe-to-updates-to-navigation-lifecycle) to check whether the component is focused or not.

You'll need

> **didFocus**: the screen focused (if there was a transition, the transition completed)

```
componentDidMount () {
    this._getUser();
    this._onFocusListener = this.props.navigation.addListener('didFocus', (payload) => {
      this._getCases();
    });
}
```

and remove it once the component gets unmounted.

```
componentWillUnmount () {
      this._onFocusListener.remove()
}
```

Comment: It seems that the listener takes a payload so should i pass some data to it from the page i'm navigating from ?

Comment: `payload` is option , you can get the screen details from it, `prevScreen`, `action` etc.

Comment: componentWillUnmount is a lifecycle callback ? .. what about using in-app notification ? can i do it the same way ? I mean in case user accepted the case ..

Comment: The in-app-notification should be on the `root` component, therefore you should use the `notification listener` instead of `navigation listener`, since it component will never be unmounted until the app gets closed.

Comment: thanks that worked .. but i'm having a problem in the styling of the notification, any chance you might help me in it ?

Comment: You might need to another question with relevant details, i'll take a look once I'm available. Thanks.

Comment: Okay i will .. Thanks to you